# Mediarecorder setParameter failed (setAudioSamplingRate)

Tags: android, audio, parameters, mediarecorder, sampling

I try to build an app where there is a record function in. I want the user to be able to choose the record quality, one of the options is AAC recording. I am using the code below, but I keep getting errors on setting the audioSamplingRate.. any ideas?

```
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                    mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(96000);
                    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```

and the error

```
04-29 10:32:17.477: E/MediaRecorder(18750): setParameters(audio-param-sampling-rate=96000) failed: -22
04-29 10:32:17.477: E/com.test.com.AudioRecorder(18750): setParameter failed.
04-29 10:32:17.477: E/com.test.com.AudioRecorder(18750): prepare() method called on illegal state
```

Comment: 96 kHz is a very high sample rate, and is not guaranteed to be supported. I suggest that you try a common sample rate <= 48 kHz (e.g. 48000, 44100, 22050, 16000, 8000).

Comment: I tried setting it to 16000, doesn't return the initial error, but another one.. the following error: 04-29 12:15:09.989: E/MediaRecorder(23954): prepare failed: -2147483648
04-29 12:15:09.989: E/com.test.com.AudioRecorder(23954): prepare failed.

Answer (score 0):

Every audio sampling rate is not supported in devices. so,if it is not supported it will give error or clipped internally to make it suitable.for quality you can set audio encoding bit rate with sample rate.44100 sample rate is supported by all android devices according to its audiorecorder documentation.you can use bit rate according to your need.this formula may help you

Bit rate = (sampling rate) × (bit depth) × (number of channels)

Bit depth is generally 8 in android devices.